# Create a nested list based on tree relationship

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a datatype that consists of multiple tuples in a list. It represents the relationship of parent-child.

For example, `[('A', 1), ('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2) ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2), ('C',)]` where the tuples can either have 1, 2, or three items with the format of (*letter, number, number*). In the above example, `('B', 1)` is the parent of `('B', 1, 1)` and `('B', 1, 2)`, and so on until we reach just a letter.

My question is, how can I create a function that will receive something like the example above and create a nested list where the similar orders and letters/numbers will be grouped together.

For instance, how do I create a function that will take something like:

```
[('A', 1), ('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2), ('B', 2), ('B', 3), ('C',)]
```

and turn it into:

```
[[('A', 1), [('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2)] ('A', 3)], [[('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2)], ('B', 2), ('B', 3)], ('C',)]
```

Also note that the list will come presorted already in alphabetical and numerical order. Only the lowest order tuples are in the input list as well. (Parental tuples will not appear in the input list if their children are present)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that using a list is a good idea here? It looks more like a tree-like structure with fast lookup is appropriate, like a customer "tree" object, or a dictionary (of dictionaries, etc.) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

We basically can iterate over the tuples, and for each tuple recursively "dive" into the data structure, and add that element. I think however that a list is, at least for an intermediate structure, not appropriate. A dictionary allows fast retrieval, hence it will boost updating.

```
def to_nested_list(tuples):
    data = {}
    for tup in tuples:
        elem = data
        for ti in tup:
            elem = elem.setdefault(ti, {})
    stck = []
    def to_list(source, dest):
        for k, v in source.items():
            stck.append(k)
            if v:
                dest.append(to_list(v, []))
            else:
                dest.append(tuple(stck))
            stck.pop()
        return dest
    return to_list(data, [])
```

For the given sample data, we thus first construct a dictionary that looks, before the `stck = []` line, like:

```
{'A': {1: {}, 2: {1: {}, 2: {}}, 3: {}}, 'B': {1: {1: {}, 2: {}}}, 'C': {}}
```

next we "harvest" the tuples of this structure, by iterating over the dictionary recursively, and each time if the corresponding value is *not* empty, adding a tuple we construct based on the "call path" to the corresponding sublist.

For example:

```
>>> to_nested_list([('A', 1), ('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2), ('C',)]) 
[[('A', 1), [('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2)], ('A', 3)], [[('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2)]], ('C',)]
```

This works for tuples of arbitrary length, as long as the elements of these tuples are all *hashable* (strings and integers are hashable, so we are safe here if the tuples contain only *letter*s and *number*s).

That being said, I'm not sure that using a nested list is a good idea anyway. Such list will result in the fact that it can take a lot of time to verify that the list contains a certain tuple, since the elements of the list do not "hint" about the prefix of that tuple. I think the `data` dictionary is probable a better representation.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
a = [('A', 1), ('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2), ('B', 2), ('B', 3), ('C',)]
```

The following solution works for trees with any depth:

First, a helper function that wraps each node with excess brackets if needed

```
def self_wrap(x, n):
    output = x
    for _ in range(n):
        output = [output]
    return output
```

Now, the main loop:

```
out_list = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    # add 0th element to out_list
    if i == 0:
        out_list.append(self_wrap(a[i], len(a[i])-1))
        continue

    # determine the appropriate bracket level to add a[i]
    prev_list = curr_list = out_list
    j = 0
    while min(len(a[i-1]), len(a[i])) > j and a[i-1][j] == a[i][j]:
        prev_list, curr_list = curr_list, curr_list[-1]
        print(curr_list, i, j)
        j += 1
    left_over_len = len(a[i]) - j - 1

    # override if last item was parent
    if j == len(a[i-1]):
        prev_list[-1] = self_wrap(a[i], left_over_len + 1)
        continue

    # append a[i] to appropriate level and wrap with additional brackets if needed
    curr_list.append(self_wrap(a[i], left_over_len) if left_over_len > 0 else a[i])

print(out_list)
```

This prints

```
[[('A', 1), [('A', 2, 1), ('A', 2, 2)], ('A', 3)], [[('B', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2)], ('B', 2), ('B', 3)], ('C',)]
```

as expected.

---

As people have pointed out, this structure is not very efficient. There are 2 reasons:

1. redundant information
2. lists are hard to manipulate/lookup

That being said, the is probably the only way to represent paths.